# How to pull data from multiple sheets in Google Spreadsheets 1 and transfer to multiple sheets in Google Spreadsheets 2?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, migrate-data

I don't have much experience with script editor, but I am trying to figure out a solution to my problem. Basically, I made a task list in Google Spreadsheets (let's call this GS1). This task list has multiple sheets. It has eight sheets and each sheet is identical in columns and rows. I am only interested in data from B3:I28.

At 8 PM each day, I'd like to take each sheet from GS1 starting from B3 to I28 and copy it to another Google Spreadsheets ("GS2") that also has eight sheets (exact same sheet names and sheet formats, etc). However, I want data from sheet 1 in GS1 to copy data to it's respective sheet 1 in GS2.

Data to copy from each sheet is in the range B3:I28 and paste it in the same location.

Is this possible?

I am not sure if pulling data or pushing data would be more likely and this will decide which GS will have the script.

Answer (score 1):

Copying data from other spreadsheets is certainly possible with the `IMPORTRANGE` formula. Example usage form one of my spreadsheets:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/35A4onc5he6l-dy3K_R6zMPd2Nc7o4LjFFEQA8Cx0hCE","April!A2:AH6")
```

Don't know how to answer about the automation of doing this only at a specified time during the day. Normally `IMPORTRANGE` works as soon as you open the target spreadsheet.